# Is there a more efficient way to merge models than hand checking every property?

Tags: c#

I am building an API whereby I only want to send an update for certain properties if the caller has included those properties in the body of the HTTP call.

I am currently doing the below.. but it seems very clunky. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
    public void MergePerson(Person basePerson, Person updatedPerson)
    {
        if (updatedPerson.Title != null)
            basePerson.Title = updatedPerson.Title;

        if (updatedPerson.Initials != null)
            basePerson.Initials = updatedPerson.Initials;

        if (updatedPerson.FirstName != null)
            basePerson.FirstName = updatedPerson.FirstName;

        if (updatedPerson.LastName != null)
            basePerson.LastName = updatedPerson.LastName;

        if (updatedPerson.Sex != null)
            basePerson.Sex = updatedPerson.Sex;

        if (updatedPerson.DateOfBirth != null)
            basePerson.DateOfBirth = updatedPerson.DateOfBirth;

        if (updatedPerson.JobTitle != null)
            basePerson.JobTitle = updatedPerson.JobTitle;

        <<< snip >>>
```

Because of this as well... I've had to set things like bools to non-nullable so that I can confirm that they were actually passed as opposed to just set to the default of false.

My concern is that one day I'll add new fields to the model and forget to add them here.

Comment: Don't know about easier but a one line would be `basePerson.Title = updatedPerson.Title != null ? updatedPerson.Title : "otherwise";` and so on (replacing *otherwise* with what default value you want).

Comment: Thanks.. but I don't want the "otherwise" section..

Comment: You can use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) for this. Make a for-loop and assign them values via reflection

Answer (score 2):

what you want to do is called **Patch**

check this code,

```
public class Car 
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Make { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 500000)]
    public float Price { get; set; }
}

public class CarPatch
{
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Make { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public int? Year { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 500000)]
    public float? Price { get; set; }
}   

public class CarsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly CarsContext _carsCtx = new CarsContext();

    // PATCH /api/cars/{id}
    public Car PatchCar(int id, CarPatch car)
    {
    var carTuple = _carsCtx.GetSingle(id);
    if (!carTuple.Item1)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }

    Patch<CarPatch, Car>(car, carTuple.Item2);

    // Not required but better to put here to simulate the external storage.
    if (!_carsCtx.TryUpdate(carTuple.Item2))
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }

    return carTuple.Item2;
}

// private helpers
private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]> TypePropertiesCache = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>();

private void Patch<TPatch, TEntity>(TPatch patch, TEntity entity)
    where TPatch : class
    where TEntity : class
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = TypePropertiesCache.GetOrAdd(
        patch.GetType(), 
        (type) => type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
    {
        PropertyInfo orjProp = entity.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
        object value = prop.GetValue(patch);
        if (value != null)
        {
            orjProp.SetValue(entity, value);
        }
    }
}
}
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/tugberkugurlu/7318417)

Comment: This looks good.. how would it work though with things such as a List<T>? I assume the above is going to replace the list rather than just add in the missing values?

Comment: For List you have to handle it outside patch method, select the item from list that you need to patch and then call patch()

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this with reflection:

```
public static void MapPersons(object basePerson, object updatedPerson)
{
    var sourceT = basePerson.GetType();
    var sourceProps = sourceT.GetProperties();

    var targetT = updatedPerson.GetType();
    var targetProps = targetT.GetProperties();

    foreach (var sProp in sourceProps)
    {
        var sourceValue = sProp.GetValue(basePerson, null);
        var propIndex = Array.IndexOf(targetProps, sProp);
        if (propIndex != -1)
        {
            var tProp = targetProps[propIndex];
            tProp.SetValue(updatedPerson, sourceValue);
        }
    }
}
```

But there are a lot of powerful tools out here like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/). They will handle that for you.